# What do the letters 's.o.s.' mean in annotations of a person's service in wartime S.O.E.? Well-known phrase, or cryptic?

Tags: terminology

I came across the following note when researching National Archives:-

'28.7.44    Part 111 orders advised:  21371 has been s.o.s.  I.S.R.B. w.e.f. 21.7.44'

I know what the other abbreviations mean, but not what the s.o.s. means in this context.

Comment: Please add the meaning of the other abbreviation, as helpful context.

Comment: ISRB is presumably the Inter-Services Research Bureau, which was a nom-de-guerre of SOE. w.e.f is "with effect from".

Comment: Questions of this nature come up quite often on Genealogy.SE.  You may get a better answer there.

Answer (score 3):

I believe *s.o.s.* here means "struck off strength" that is, "removed from service" or "posted to another unit". *Strength* here is [*headcount*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/headcount), the number of people employed.

A member of HM Forces has [posted so](http://ww2talk.com/forums/topic/15663-x-lists-service-records/#entry582336) in the past:

> SOS is definitely Struck off strength, in other words, posted to another unit.

ISRB is a code name for the Special Operations Executive, so agent 21371 stopped working for them on 21 July 1944.